# Conditional SQL report

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table that contains:

```
Serial#  ColorCount   BWCount
==============================
12345            23        56
80023             0       459
22903             1       999
```

and I want to generate a report that looks like:

```
SN     Description    Value
==============================
12345  "BWCount"      56
12345  "ColourCount"  23
80023  "BWCount"      459
22903  "BWCount"      999
22903  "ColourCount"  1
```

so that...

1. the BWCount and ColourCount values are output as different rows, and
2. if the ColourCount value for a device (SN) is zero it is not output

Is this even possible with raw SQL? And if yes, please show me how or point me in the right direction. I've done some work with MySQL but only some simple queries. This is something I have never seen done before.

Comment: Search for `Pivoting` in Google; you will get a lot of sample answer.

Comment: @Rahul That's not a pivot, it's an UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `UNION` two queries to return the data you need, for example:

```
SELECT Serial, 'BWCount' AS description, BWCount AS value
FROM serial 
UNION
SELECT Serial, 'ColourCount' AS description, ColourCount AS value
FROM serial 
WHERE ColourCount > 0
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f97b6/3